# swift user login redirect with mmdrawer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, mmdrawercontroller

I have an issue with my redirect after a user has loged in. I am using mmdrawer so i need to initiate it so the left and right menu show up on the next page the user should be redirected too. However nothing is happening. Earlier i had a solution that redirected the member but broke the app so it crashed. I am using the following code to try to redirect the user and initiate the redirect. It works when i use it on other view controllers as code in a ibaction, and it works as it should.

```
var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Memberarea") as! userOverview

var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
```

It works as it should normally but not in the code i am using below. I am using it in the following code.

```
import UIKit

class LoginPage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func signinTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        var username:NSString = txtUsername.text
        var password:NSString = txtPassword.text
        var database:NSString = "bfdlogin" as NSString

        if ( username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") ) {
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Please enter Username and Password"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        } else {

            var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)&database=\(database)"

            NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

            var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxxx")!

            var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

            var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

            var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = postData
            request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            var reponseError: NSError?
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

            if ( urlData != nil ) {
                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

                NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {
                    var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                    var error: NSError?

                    let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary

                    let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                    //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                    NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                        var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                        prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                        prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                        prefs.synchronize()

                        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView.title = "Aanmelden  Succesvol"
                        alertView.message = "Klik ok om verder te gaan"
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView.show()

                        var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Memberarea") as! userOverview

                        var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

                        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
                    } else {
                        var error_msg:NSString

                        if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                            error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                        } else {
                            error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                        }
                        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                        alertView.message = error_msg as String
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView.show()

                    }

                } else {
                    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                    alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()
                }
            } else {
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
                if let error = reponseError {
                    alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
                }
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }
        }
    }


    //function to hide the keyboard when tapping outside a text field

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true;
    }

    //hide keyboard when tapping outside a field

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong and why it doesn't want to initiate the redirect. The old code which is a larger version of mmdrawer which i have in my appdelegate does redirect but crashes the app. How can i solve this. I am still pretty new swift.

Thanks.

Comment: When ever I have issues like this it most likely that I messed a setup in the storyboard somewhere.  Example I have an app that on the first time it runs it sends you to the setup screens. After the setups screens completed and the user logged in for the first time they would get a blank screen. But it would work just fine if they closed and went back in. The solution was I need to add a navigation controller before the screen after the login screen. Because other wise the view did not get one so it would end up blank.

Comment: I have looked at that, but i still can't find the issue, i really need to get some more insight into the way how to perform the redirect.

Comment: Post the message yo get when it crashes.

Comment: that is the strange thing i do not get a crash log, i have tried to record it and nothing. also with the code above, it does nothing. it just set the user to logged in and then it stays on the same page. It looks like the code is not being executed. Maybe i should call it as a function, would that work?

Comment: Have tried put breaks in so that you can the values of your if statements.  You maybe getting a nil value. I would try placing one at this code if ( urlData != nil )

Comment: well the out goes good, i have a log that says everything goes great and user is logged in and the response is success. SO the problem is really at the point i trying to redirect the user after they push ok on the uialert.